How can I call a method within the same object literal where it's defined in JavaScript?
const objTest = {
  testFunctionToDoubleAValue: (testParameter) => testParameter * 2,
  testValue: 1,
  testValueDoubled: testFunctionToDoubleAValue(1),
}

I tried to access a function inside the same object it was defined within, but I didn't knew how...
